# Sheets : For loop to update a value from multiple cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have not used excel or google sheets much and am trying to write a simple fragment of code.

```
finalValue = 0
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    if (Ci == 'A') {
        finalValue += Di
    }
    else {
        finalValue -= Di
    }
}
```

(C and D are the columns)

I can't figure out how to write a global variable and update it in a for loop in google sheets.

Comment: Have you trried Googling ***"google apps script global variables"*** ?  Where, and what did you find out?  Please check out the [tour] as well as  [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and also [mcve] and [ask] to learn more about how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: I wasn't aware there is something called as "google apps script". I was looking at the loops and the ifs of the inbuilt sheets functions and couldn't figure it out. Hence posted the question. You could have been nice and simply pointed me in that direction. Sometimes you aren't aware of a particular functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Built-in spreadsheets functions don't have  loops or variables. The arguments of functions are scalar values or references to cells (or arrays of those). My suggestion is to back off out of the "I need a loop" idea and state the goal as

> Add the values in D1:D20 where the corresponding C entry is string 'A', and subtract those values where it is not 'A'.

Which is done with `sumif` or `sumifs`; I prefer the latter because it's more powerful and its order of arguments makes more sense to me.

```
=sumifs(D1:D20, C1:C20, "=A") - sumifs(D1:D20, C1:C20, "<>A")
```

---

Then there is a whole different aspect of scripts (VBA in Excel, Google Apps Script in Google Sheets); they are for the situation where built-in functions do not suffice. But [there are quite complex computations one can do with built-in functions](https://xkcd.com/1667/).